# Python & Tkinter: parsing text from tkinter scrolledtext and getting button to run definition which begins parsing process

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, text-parsing, local-variables

I currently have a working script which parses text data from a text file.

Instead of using a text file, I am interested in using a Tkinter scrolledtext to hold the data instead of a text file.  I would then like to have a Tkinter button which would run the parsing function and parse the data as it normally would do when I run the parsing script with the data from a text file.

I ran into a problem of local and global variables when I tried to convert my working script into a definition to run via a tkinter button.  As a simple fix, I instead added my working script directly to the new code which contained the tkinter code.  The working script was then set into a loop that would be activated when the tkinter button was pressed which called a new definition that simply changed a boolean.  The changed boolean value was suppose to make the working script then run.

I thought that this would work, but it doesn't.  If someone could (1) help me understand either how to properly run my working script as a definition called through a tkinter button or (2) to help me fix my "fix" in which the working script is not converted into a definition, but held within a loop, I would be very grateful!

Please see below for the "simple fix" version of the script: (please see @Mike - SMT post below for current script - I passed the word limit trying to add both the old script and the new testable .txt file into this post)

Below is a testable .txt file.  (updated)

```
asdfasdfasdfasd asdf™
BLAH asdfasdf asdff 
asdfasdfsadf & asdfasd
asdf
asd asdf

 asdff
 asdfaf
 asdfasd
 asdfasd 
asdff asdfasdf / asdfasdf asdfas asdfasdf asdfasdf / asdfa asdf BLAH-2020-02-0001 asdffd




    asdf asdf asdff asdf asdf asdfas asdf asdfas asdf asdfast asdfdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdfasdfasd asdfasd sdfas df asdfas df  ffffffasdfasd asdfasdfasd      asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdfsdf  asdfasdfasdfasdf asdfasdfasdfsdf asdf asdf asdff asdf asdf asdfas asdf asdfas asdf asdfast asdfdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdf asdff asdf asdf asdfas asdf asdfas asdf asdfast asdfdfasdfasdfasdf Read More ...



asdfasdf sa








as asdff asdff
Adf f asdf



BLAH-2020-02-0001

Submitted: 29-Feb-2020; Last Updated: 03-Mar-2020; 12314 days, 112314 hours in review

Title Title Title Title Title Title


bob, blah (proxy) (contact); bob2, blah2; bob3, blah3; bob4, blah4


Short Report


asdff - asdffasdf asdf sdf asdff asdfas:  


dfgsdfg fg (Due 10-Mar-2020)

fg: sdf Agsdfgs
sdfg: sdgfsd sdfg, BLAH
ADM: sdfgg, sdfgsd (proxy)

   HTML    PDF     Supplemental Files   Original Files     Abstract     Cover Letter     External Searches   





- sdfg sdfgg sdfgsdf


Date Submitted:

29-Feb-2020

Admin:

sdfgg, sdfgsd  AU REV VIEW ADM PROD 
proxy   
Date to Admin:

29-Feb-2020

Admin:

 Admin  
Date to Admin:

03-Mar-2020

sdfgg-sdf-sdgfsd:

sdfgsdg sdfgg, BLAH  AU REV DE EIC ADM VIEW PROD    
Date to sdfgg-gsd-sdfg:

03-Mar-2020





- sdfgsd sdfgsdf sdgg


sdfgs dfgsdg  dfgsdfgdfg  asdf asdf asdff asdf asdf asdfas asdf asdfas asdf asdfast asdfdfasdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdff asdf asdf asdfas asdf asdfas asdf asdfast asdfdfasdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdff asdf asdf asdfas asdf asdfas asdf asdfast asdfdfasdfasdfasdfasdf asdf asdff asdf asdf asdfas asdf asdfas asdf asdfast asdfdfasdfasdfasdf





- sdfgsdn sdfgsd




sdfgsdgsd fg

sdfgsdg sdfgsd

sdfgs sdgsdg

sdfgsdg dfgsd & sdgg

sdfgsd
sdgsd


BLAH-2020-02-0001

Title Title Title Title Title sdfg 

29-Feb-2020





- asdfasd-asdfasdf asdfa


asdfas - Manuscript type:

Short Report

Title:

Title Title Title Title Title blah

Manuscript ID:

BLAH-2020-02-0001

Funding Information:

sdfgsdfg sdfg sdgsdfgsdfg

Submitting Author:


    bob, bob  (proxy)

primary affiliation
Dr.
place place place 123
123 place place place
China

Authors & Institutions:



Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
China


Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
China


Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
China


Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
China


Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
China

Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
China


Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
China


Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
Australia


Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
South Korea

Contact Author (populates the ##PROLE_AUTHOR_..## e-mail tags):


Dr. name name
place place place 123
123 place place place
Japan

Running Head:

Title Title Title Title blah blah

Discipline:

Dis Type blah blah

Keywords:

asdf asdf, asdfas, asdf asdfa, Tasdfsdf, asdfasasdf

Additional Keywords:

asdfas 

Author Recommended Reviewers:

person 1
person 2

Author Opposed Reviewers:

Author's Cover Letter:

dear person,
blah blah blah
cover letter
blahb blah blah
blah blah blah

sincerely,
person

If you have been invited to submit an article for a supplement, please select the title of the supplement:


Manuscript Details - Metadata (Please use numbers only)
Content Information
 Number of words (excluding the title page, abstract, references, acknowledgements, and wording for tables and figures):    
1761

 Number of manuscript pages:    
12

 Number of tables (use 0 for none): 
2

Illustration Information
 Total number of figures (use 0 for none):  
2

 Number of colour figures (use 0 for none): 
0



Publication Charge
 zsasdf sdf asdf as dfa sdfasdfasdf asdfas df asdf as df as dfdfasdfasdfasd zsasdf sdf asdf as dfa sdfasdfasdf asdfas df asdf as df as dfdfasdfasdfasdzsasdf sdf asdf as dfa sdfasdfasdf asdfas df asdf as df as dfdfasdfasdfasdzsasdf sdf asdf as dfa sdfasdfasdf asdfas df asdf as df as dfdfasdfasdfasd

zsasdf sdf asdf as dfa sdfasdfasdf asdfas df asdf as df as dfdfasdfasdfasdzsasdf sdf asdf as dfa sdfasdfasdf asdfas df asdf as df as dfdfasdfasdfasdzsasdf sdf asdf as dfa sdfasdfasdf asdfas df asdf as df as dfdfasdfasdfasdzsasdf sdf asdf as dfa sdfasdfasdf asdfas df asdf as df as dfdfasdfasdfasd zsasdf sdf asdf as dfa sdfasdfasdf asdfas df asdf as df as dfdfasdfasdfasd
Supplement articles: please select the option "I believe a third-party will pay..." below, and enter AAA as the code (stands for "BLAH Supplement Sponsor").

If your manuscript is accepted, you will be given the option of paying by credit card or invoice. If you believe that payment for your article is covered by a society, institutional or funding agency arrangement, please let us know using the form below.

Not sure if payment for your article could be covered by your institution or funding agency? Use our Institute/Funder Policy Finder tool to check: http://sdfgsdfgsdgsdgsdg.html

Who Will Pay


I accept responsibility for paying the publication charge on this article.

If your manuscript is accepted, you will be able to pay by credit card, invoice, or pro forma.

(Please see the “Discounts That May Apply” section for a list of institutions and funding agencies that have agreed to cover a portion of the publication fees.)


I believe a third-party will pay the publication charge for this article.

Some institutions and funding agencies have agreed to be invoiced directly and pay the sdfgsd sdfgsdfgsd sdfgsdg article publication charge (sdfgs) for their affiliated researchers. To check your eligibility, go to http://www.sdfgsdfg and find the affiliated institution or funder of the corresponding author, then copy the code and paste it here.
    Please enter institution code here:

    Please enter your funder and grant / project number if your institution requires this information in order to pay the APC:



I request a waiver of the publication charge for this article.

We offer a complete or partial fee waiver on a case-by-case basis for individual autdfghdfh dfhdfhdfhdfghdfhdfghdfhdfgdfh gfhdfhdfhdf dfghdfh (internal use)

Discounts That May Apply

Please select from the drop-down menus below for all discounts you wish to claim. Please note that the single, highest discount will apply.
Society Membership Discount
If the Corresponding Author is a member of the asdfasdf fasdf asdf asdasdf and wishes to request a discount (as applicable), please select it from the list below.
If the Corresponding Author is not an dsfgs dgfsdgsd sdfgsdgfishes to apply before submitting, the membership application form is available at: www.sdfgsdfgsdfg. To qualify for the discount, please supply your membership number during original submission. The discount will not be applied if you become a member after original submission, or if you suspend your membership before acceptance of your manuscript.
Please enter the society membership ID number of the corresponding author so we can verify your membership. If you don't know your membership ID you can request this from msdfgsdfgsd@sdgsdfgs.org:
For office use only:  dfasdf asdffdasasdf asdf
 asdfasdfasdf asdfasdf
The institutions or funding agencies listed below have agreed to cover a portion of the article publication charges in sdfgsd gsdgsdgfsdfgsdfgsdg for their affiliated researchers. If you are a corresponding author affiliated with one of the organizations listed, please select it from the list below:
Other Discount
If you have received another type of discount code, such as a promotional discount code via e-mail or brochure, please enter it below:
Eligibility for institutional payment via asdf asfasdfasdfasdfasdfas is based on the date of submission of an article. If your institution ceases to have an active account/partnership arrangement prior to completion of the article submission process, your article will not be eligible for institutional/funder payment.


Submission Information - Confirm the following:
 Confirm that the manuscript has been submitted solely to this journal and is not published, in press, or submitted elsewhere.  




Conflict of Interest
wer wert wet wet wetwert wet wert we requires that all authors disclose any potential sources of conflict of interest. Any interest or relationship, financial or otherwise, that might be perceived as influencing an author’s objectivity is considered a potential source of conflict of interest. These must be disclosed when directly relevant or indirectly related to the work that the authors describe in their manuscript. Potential sources of conflict of interest include but are not limited to patent or stock ownership, membership of a company board of directors, membership of an advisory board or committee for a company, and consultancy for or receipt of speaker’s fees from a company. The existence of a conflict of interest does not preclude publication in this journal.

If the authors have no conflict of interest to declare, they must also state this at submission. It is the responsibility of the corresponding author to review this policy with all authors and to collectively list in the cover letter (if applicable) to the Editor-in-Chief, in the manuscript (in the footnotes, Conflict of Interest or Acknowledgments section), and in the online submission system ALL pertinent commercial and other relationships.
 Do you or any of your co-authors have a conflict of interest to declare?
No

Confirm that you have stated this conflict of interest in the footnotes, Conflict of Interest or Acknowledgments section of your manuscript as required by the Journal (see the Instructions to Authors).


Provide details and include this information below.


Previously Submitted to  sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfg
 Has this manuscript previously
- been submitted via  sdfgsdfgsdfgsdfsdfgsdfgsdfg previous submission site and is now being submitted either for final acceptance or after revision
- been submitted via the  sdfgsdfgsdfgsdgfsdf sdgfsdfg website and received a revision decision [revised papers should be submitted as “revisions” and not as “new” papers]
- been submitted to  sdfgsdfgsdfgsdgsdfgsdfgsdfcted?
If either of the above is true please answer "Yes". 
No

If yes, please state previous sdfg sdfg sdgfsdgsdfgsdfgsdfgsd:


Open Access Agreement
 Confirm that all authors of this submission have read and understood the journal's policy concerning the completion of the Open Access Agreement. This form will be requested if your paper is accepted. Further information can be found in the journal's Author Guidelines.  




Supporting Information
 We allow submission of "Sdfhdfggh dfh". Go to https://dfgsdgf sdgsdfgsdfgdfgsd.html to access the fgh dfhdfh guidelines for the submission of Supporting Information. If you wish to submit Supporting Information, please select the file designation “Supporting Information for review and publication” when uploading your files. Please note that we would encourage you, where possible and appropriate, to include such information in an Appendix in your main document instead of designating it as Supporting Information.

Does your submission include any supporting information files for publication?


Yes



No



 Ethics
 Please insert your ethical statement below. This should include approval by any ethical boards and your consent or consent waiver procedure. If your article does not require an ethical statement (for example if it is a review), please state this. Your ethical statement should also be included in your methods section.
The case we reported are consent for the study.



 Dates of data collection
 Please state the dates between which your data was collected. Literature reviews should list when the review was completed and the dates of the literature reviewed. This information should also be included in the methods section of your main article and abstract.
 sdfgsdfgsdgsd gsdfgsdgsdfgsdgsdgfsdgfsdgsdgsdfg sdf sdfg sdfgsdfgsd.







- Plagiarism Check iThenticate User Guide


Crossref Similarity Check logo  
Overall Similarity Index Percentage: 25%

Report complete. View the Originality Report.





- Forward to Viewing


Viewing



- Forward to Admin


 fgjgfj, fgjgh  (assign a different person)



- Admin Checklist (Date Completed: 03-Mar-2020 )


Is the submission complete, are all files submitted in an acceptable format and is the manuscript ready for review? 


 Has the author requested a fee waiver? 


Have all co-author names been uploaded by the submitting author?    


Is the manuscript within the scope of/suitable for the journal? 


Does the manuscript main document include keywords? 


If the author has claimed a society membership discount, has membership been verified and society discount code provided (Manuscript Information tab>Author-Supplied Data>Edit This Information)?   


Supplement articles only: Has author selected "BLAH Supplement Sponsor" as their funder? Is manuscript on list of expected supplemental articles? If yes, copy Supplement Title into "Comments to Payment Administrator" below. If no, unsubmit paper and ask author to select another payment option.  




Comments to Payment Administrator:







- Export History 


Export Method

Date Exported

History

Remove

Batch:
Submitted ms export

03-Mar-2020

Exported to file blah-2020-02-0001-20200303110924.zip
Successfully uploaded blah-2020-02-0001-20200303110924.zip via FTP file to sdfgsdfg.com.





Assign to Batch:


Export Now:




- Editor-in-Chief List


Order

Name

Status

History

Remove




 Editorial Office, BLAH
(assign a different person)



Assigned (03-Mar-2020)





- EIC Decision


Make a Decision


Accept


Minor Revision


Major Revision


Reject


Reject without Review

Decision comments (internal use only):



Reviews






- Assign to Issue


Not assigned to issue.

Assign to:






- Companion Papers


Manuscript ID

Manuscript Title

Date Submitted

Author

Status

Delete

Type






- Flag This Manuscript



Leave this manuscript unflagged

      Accepted Manuscript             Plagiarism check needed

      .R2             
                  Resubmission
                  .R1
      TDA with Reports            TDA without Reports






- Notes


Note Title

Updated By

Updated On

Edit

Delete

This document has no notes.





dfghdfhdfhd fgh dfhdfgh
df hdfhdfghdfhdfhdfghdfhdf
dfhdfghdfghdfghdfgh
dfhdfghdfhdfhdfhd

 @dfghdfhdfh  |   dfghdfh dfhdfhh  |   dfhdf dfhdfh  |   dfhdf df dfhdf

 Admin: dfghdfhdf dfhdfhh |
```

Comment: `global doWork` is not doing what you think. Defining `global` in the global namespace does absolutely nothing. The `global` must be in the function. Also everything after the `mainloop()` wont run until the root window is destroyed. That said there is a lot of code here. Reduce it down to a small testable example. We only need one text, one button, a function or 2 and your loop.

Comment: `command=clickWork(doWork)` needs to be a lambda or your function just needs to look ad `doWork` from in the function. try `command=lambda:clickWork(doWork)`.

Comment: You are also redefining a variables multiple times before they are ever used. You can fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot going on here and a lot that needs to be changed.

1. Your code after `mainloop()` wont work until you close the application. So instead lets move your parsing code into the function that was meant to update onWork.
2. You can generate most of your label and entry fields using a loop. This will help reduce lines and make things easier to read. With list of entry fields you can use the list + index values to get what you need.
3. You had a lot of code that did nothing or was never called. I have removed all that from the example.
4. `oneCountries` should probably be a list in a separate file that you import. If you follow PEP8 line length rules you end up adding a bunch of lines to your code.
5. I have not changed much in your parsing code except for a few small things as I do not have any data to test so I cannot write up a better version as is. That said I can see there are a lot of places things can go wrong. All your if condition have issues. For example you run a loop with the loop value of `line` then you run sub loops with the same value of `line` this will cause things to overwrite before it reaches the next if. Or you do not have an else condition if the `if` statement fails so it is possible for the rest of your code to fail without those variables being defined. So if you can provide some example file data I can update that portion.
6. You had several imports you were not using. Try to keep your imports clean and concise.

With all the unused code removed and other code reworked your example went from 320 lines to 140+.
Reworked code below. Let me know if you have any questions:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from itertools import islice
import re


def click_work():
    print('clicked!!')
    print('do work is now in the function!!')
    the_file = txt1.get('1.0', 'end-1c').split('\n')
    print(the_file)
    for line in the_file:
        line = line.strip()
        # print(line)
        if re.match(r'Blah-2020'.upper(), line.upper()):
            print('the_id', line)
            the_id = line  # had to rename due to "id" being a built in function.
        if re.match(r'Submitted: ', line):
            date = line
            for line1 in islice(the_file, 2):
                title = line1
            for line2 in islice(the_file, 3):
                authors = line2
            for line3 in islice(the_file, 3):
                ms_type = line3
            for line4 in islice(the_file, 3):
                extra_data = line4

        if line.startswith('Submitting Author:'):
            country_parsing = True
        elif line.startswith('Running Head:'):
            country_parsing = False
        else:
            country_parsing = False

        print(country_parsing)
        if country_parsing:
            for d in countries:
                if d in line:
                    my_other_list.append(d)

        if line.startswith('Author\'s Cover Letter:'):
            cover_letter_parsing = True
        elif line.startswith('If you have been invited to submit an article for a supplement, '
                             'please select the title of the supplement:'):
            cover_letter_parsing = False
        else:
            cover_letter_parsing = False

        if cover_letter_parsing:
            cover_letter.append(line)

        if re.match(r'Discipline:', line):
            for sub_line in islice(the_file, 2):
                discipline = sub_line
        # print(line)
        # print(r'Overall Similarity Index Percentage:' in line)
        if r'Overall Similarity Index Percentage:' in line:
            ithenticate = line

    # note several lines will error if a condition was not met previously.
    # so if I were you I would write in some default values just in case match fails.
    ithenticate = float(re.sub('%', '', ithenticate.split(':')[1])) / 100
    first_author = authors.split(',')[0]
    date = date.split(':')[1].split(';')[0].strip(' ')
    id_short = re.sub('Blah'.upper(), '', the_id.upper())
    countries_without_duplicates = list(dict.fromkeys(my_other_list))
    cover_letter.pop(0)
    countrry = ', '.join(countries_without_duplicates)

    results = [authors, first_author, the_id, date, ms_type, discipline, ithenticate,
               id_short, extra_data, my_other_list[0], my_other_list[-1], countrry]

    for ndex, entry in enumerate(entry_list3):
        if ndex < len(results):
            entry.delete(0, 'end')
            entry.insert(0, results[ndex])

    print("@@@@@@@@@@\n@@@@@@@@@@\n@@@@@@@@@@\n")
    print("All Authors: " + authors)
    print("First Author: " + first_author)
    print("\nMS ID: " + the_id)
    print("\nMS Title: " + title)
    print("Submission date: " + date)
    print("MS type: " + ms_type)
    print("Discipline: " + discipline)
    print("iThenticate: " + str(ithenticate))
    print("MS ID (short version): " + id_short)
    print("Extra info: " + extra_data)
    print("First Author's Country: " + my_other_list[0])
    print("Last  Author's Country: " + my_other_list[-1])
    print("All Author's Countries (w/o duplicates): " + countrry)

oneCountries = "Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Andorra, Angola, Antigua & Deps, Argentina, Armenia, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Bahamas, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Barbados, Belarus, Belgium, Belize, Benin, Bhutan, Bolivia, Bosnia Herzegovina, Botswana, Brazil, Brunei, Bulgaria, Burkina, Burma, Burundi, Cambodia, Cameroon, Canada, Cape Verde, Central African Rep, Chad, Chile, China, Republic of China, Colombia, Comoros, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Republic of the Congo, Costa Rica, Côte d’Ivoire, Ivory Coast, Republic of Côte d'Ivoire, Croatia, Cuba, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Danzig, Denmark, Djibouti, Dominica, Dominican Republic, East Timor, Ecuador, Egypt, El Salvador, Equatorial Guinea, Eritrea, Estonia, Ethiopia, Fiji, Finland, France, Gabon, Gaza Strip, The Gambia, Georgia, Germany, Ghana, Greece, Grenada, Guatemala, Guinea, Guinea-Bissau, Guyana, Haiti, Holy Roman Empire, Honduras, Hungary, Iceland, India, Indonesia, Iran, Iraq, Republic of Ireland, Israel, Italy, Ivory Coast, Jamaica, Japan, Jonathanland, Jordan, Kazakhstan, Kenya, Kiribati, North Korea, South Korea, Kosovo, Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan, Laos, Latvia, Lebanon, Lesotho, Liberia, Libya, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Macedonia, Madagascar, Malawi, Malaysia, Maldives, Mali, Malta, Marshall Islands, Mauritania, Mauritius, Mexico, Micronesia, Moldova, Monaco, Mongolia, Montenegro, Morocco, Mount Athos, Mozambique, Namibia, Nauru, Nepal, Newfoundland, Netherlands, New Zealand, Nicaragua, Niger, Nigeria, Norway, Oman, Ottoman Empire, Pakistan, Palau, Panama, Papua New Guinea, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, Prussia, Qatar, Romania, Rome, Russian Federation, Rwanda, St Kitts & Nevis, St Lucia, Saint Vincent & the Grenadines, Samoa, San Marino, Sao Tome & Principe, Saudi Arabia, Senegal, Serbia, Seychelles, Sierra Leone, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, Solomon Islands, Somalia, South Africa, Spain, Sri Lanka, Sudan, Suriname, Swaziland, Sweden, Switzerland, Syria, Tajikistan, Tanzania, Thailand, Togo, Tonga, Trinidad & Tobago, Tunisia, Turkey, Turkmenistan, Tuvalu, Uganda, Ukraine, United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom, United States, Uruguay, Uzbekistan, Vanuatu, Vatican City, Venezuela, Vietnam, Yemen, Zambia, Zimbabwe"

lbl_list = ['Authors: ', '1st Author: ', 'MS ID: ', 'MS Title: ', 'Sub. Date: ',
            'MS Type: ', 'Discipline: ', 'iThenticate: ', 'Extra Info: ',
            '1st Au Country: ', 'Last Au Country: ', 'All Au Country: ', 'COI parameters: ']

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('225x225')
window.title('Title Here')
entry_list1 = []  # you can use these list to get the data from entry fields
entry_list2 = []  # you can use these list to get the data from entry fields
entry_list3 = []  # you can use these list to get the data from entry fields
bool_list = []   # you can use this list to get the data from bool vars

tk.Label(window, text='Add Copy&Paste text here', font=('Arial Bold', 10)).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')
txt1 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, height=0, width=25)
txt1.grid(column=0, row=1)
txt1.insert('insert', 'Paste the text here...')

tk.Button(window, text='Analyze the text', bg='white', fg='green',
          command=click_work).grid(column=0, row=4, sticky='w')

tk.Label(window, text='Did you download the files yet?').grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='w')
rad1 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text='yes', value=1)
rad2 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text='no', value=0)
rad1.grid(column=0, row=6, sticky='w')
rad2.grid(column=0, row=6)

tk.Label(window, text='Files:').grid(column=0, row=8, sticky='w')


for i in range(9, 15):
    tk.Label(window, text='{})'.format(i)).grid(column=0, row=9, sticky='w')
    entry_list1.append(tk.Entry(window, width=25, state='disabled'))
    entry_list1[-1].grid(column=0, row=i)
    tk.Label(window, text='~~>', font=('Arial Bold', 10)).grid(column=0, row=i, sticky='e')
    entry_list2.append(tk.Entry(window, width=25))
    entry_list2[-1].grid(column=1, row=i, sticky='w')
    bool_list.append(tk.BooleanVar())
    bool_list[-1].set(True)
    tk.Checkbutton(window, var=bool_list[-1]).grid(column=1, row=9, sticky='e')

for ndex, value in enumerate(lbl_list):
    if ndex == 0:
        sticky1 = 'se'
        sticky2 = 's'
    else:
        sticky1 = 'ne'
        sticky2 = 'n'
    tk.Label(window, text=value).grid(column=2, row=ndex+1, sticky=sticky1)
    entry_list3.append(tk.Entry(window, width=55))
    entry_list3[-1].grid(column=3, row=ndex+1, sticky=sticky2)
    bool_list.append(tk.BooleanVar())
    bool_list[-1].set(True)
    tk.Checkbutton(window, var=bool_list[-1]).grid(column=4, row=ndex+1, sticky=sticky2)

cb_list = ['Title Page', 'Abstract', 'Ethics', 'Consent', 'Contribution', 'COI', 'Funding', 'Cover Letter']
for ndex, value in enumerate(cb_list):
    tk.Checkbutton(window, text=value).grid(column=0, row=ndex+16, sticky='w')

countries = oneCountries.split(', ')
my_other_list = []
directory = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/'
path = 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/read.txt'
cover_letter = []
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your in-depth replies are greatly appreciated.  I'll test your modified code today and let you know how it turns out.  I'll be in touch shortly.

Comment: Mike:
After running your code, I get the following error when clicking the tkinter button: (please note, this is the same error that I got previously which I described as "global/local variable issues")

Comment: clicked!!
do work is now in the function!!
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/me/Desktop/parsing test/GUICreation_added parsing function.py", line 59, in click_work
    ithenticate = float(re.sub('%', '', ithenticate.split(':')[1])) / 100
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ithenticate' referenced before assignment

Comment: @user70711 as I mentioned in point 5 this is because your if statements have failed. So you will need to decide on a default value for the variables created in thise if statements.

Comment: @user70711 I would need an example set of data to validate the rest of your code.

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll make a testable .txt file and post it here.

Comment: The Testable .txt file is now added. I had to modified the original, but it still works with my script.

Comment: @user70711 I made it past that error however in your example data `Submitting Author:` has nothing after it so your condition  `if line.startswith('Submitting Author:'):` will always fail. This will cause `my_other_list` to remain empty and thus error out on `print("First Author's Country: " + my_other_list[0])`. Do you want to update that line or have a default value if nothing is after that line.

Comment: @user70711 based on your example data I have updated my code. I also added a random country after `Submitting Author: ` So that condition would not fail.

Comment: Thanks for the updates.  I won't be able to try the code until Monday.  I'll keep you posted though and let you know how it goes.  Thanks again for your continued dedication.

Comment: Hey, I just tested the updated script and it resulted in a large number of print outs of "False", then the following error:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jacob.bursavich\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/jacob.bursavich/Desktop/parsing test/GUICreation_added parsing function.py", line 72, in click_work
    id_short, extra_data, my_other_list[0], my_other_list[-1], countrry]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: My guess is that the modified data that I provided isn't valid compared to the original text files that I am using.  I will post another text file and this time try to make it as close as possible to the original as I can.  I'll have it available in a few hours from now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I've made a new workable txt file that should work properly for testing.  If you have time, could you check your script against this updated .txt example?  thanks again for your input @Mike - SMT

Comment: Now what is strange is that my old code will run within the confines of the new click_work function but the data that it attaches to the variables is inaccurate.  I can run the exact same code, but having the text stored in a text file and the data is accurate.  I think that the problem now is with the way that the islice function works with the tkinter scrolledtext.  Maybe i need a new method for parsing out the data within the scrolltext?

Comment: Continuing with this idea, I tried to simulate reading of a .txt file using the following: "thefile = io.StringIO(txt1.get('1.0', 'end-1c'))"   ...Now islice works and the data is processed correctly!

Comment: Hey Mike.  Yeah still making a few adjustments, but the main issue is resolved.  I'll give you ++ for your answer.  Thanks again for your major contributions.  Very helpful indeed.

Comment: @user70711 glad it worked out. You still probably want to write in some default values in case your `if` conditions fail

Comment: I am building this GUI to help (non-technical people) automate a bunch of data processing.  I feel like I've got the heavy-lifting out of the way, but since its all new to me, I will undoubtedly run into more problems with Tkinter later.  I'll be posting more questions i'm sure and I hope that you have time to work with me again on them.  Take care for now :)